# How to get distinct ids from a pivot like MySQL table according to multiple row values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I have a MySQL table like the below one named **attribute_master**,

[image]

Now I want to get all the **ref_id** having `f_name = "Sam"` and `l_name = "Border"`.

How can I do that using a MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select ref_id
from mytable
where attr_name in ('f_name', 'l_name')
group by ref_id
having
    max(attr_name = 'f_name' and attr_value = 'Sam') = 1
    and max(attr_name = 'l_name' and attr_value = 'Border') = 1
```

Here is another way to express it (assuming no duplicates `(ref_id, attr_name)`):

```
select ref_id
from mytable
where (attr_name, attr_value) in (('f_name', 'Sam'), ('l_name', 'Boder'))
group by ref_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: Can you please share why we need to use `having count(*) = 2` option here?

Comment: @Sinha: this is to ensure that *both* tuples (first name and last name) did match. It would eliminate refs that have the desired first name, but not the last name (or the other way around).

Comment: Thanks, but the above query is not working for partial search as we can do with `LIKE`. If I want to search `Bord`, `('l_name', '%Bord%')` is not working.

Comment: @Sinha: this is a different question that the one your originally asked... Starting from the first queyr, you can change the having clause: `having
    max(attr_name = 'f_name' and attr_value like '%Sam%') = 1
    and max(attr_name = 'l_name' and attr_value like %'Border%') = 1